# How many zeroes are in the numerals from $m$ to $n$?

Tags: number-theory

### Counting Zeroes

If I write down the decimal representations of all natural numbers between and including $m$ and $n$, ($m \leq n$), how many zeroes will I write down? How to calculate it? $m$ and $n$ will be 32-bit integers.

For example if $m = 10$ and $n = 11$ the answer is $1$. But if $m = 13423$ and $n = 2352352454$ then what will be the answer?

Comment: Side note: Is it "I" or is it "he"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 1 zero (for the last digit) for every 10 numbers,
there is 10 additionnal zero every 100 numbers,
there is 100 additionnal zero every 1000 numbers...

This would imply that the numbers of zeros is approximatly

$$\sum_{k \geq 1} 10^{k-1}\left\lfloor \frac{n}{10^k} \right\rfloor$$

But this formula is not exact, as there is a problem when you count $10^k$ zeros in one group. The formula become :

$$\sum_{k \geq 1} 
\left\lbrace \begin{array} 
.10^{k-1}\left\lfloor \frac{n}{10^k}\right\rfloor & \text{if} & \text{k=1 or the k-th digit is not 0} \\
10^{k-1}\left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{10^k}\right\rfloor -1\right) +n+1- 10^k\left\lfloor \frac{n}{10^k}\right\rfloor & \text{if} & \text{the k-th digit is 0 and k is not 1}\\
\end{array}\right.$$

Edit : this formula seems to work. I tested it on some numbers with the computer

Comment: This will only be approximate, as the exact answer will depend on the specific numbers in question (to say nothing of the fact that the formula does not yield a whole number in general).  Still it will be a good approximation, particularly for large values of $n-m$ (n should be replaced with $n-m$, however.

Comment: This function always give whole numbers : $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is the flooring function and always give an integer

Comment: @Paul:  the floor function assures we get a whole number.  It will not be correct, though.  For $123$ it gets $12+1=13$, instead of 10 (ones up to 100) +3 (ones 100-123)+10 (tens 100-109)=23

Comment: @RossMillikan Oh yes, I forgot to multiply by $10^{k-1}$

Comment: @RossMillikan, ah, I didn't look at the "brackets" too closely.

Comment: This is still not correct.  For 101 or 123 the k=2 term contributes 10 for the zeros from 100 through 109 in the tens place, but they aren't there for 101

Comment: Indeed, this formula is just an approximation. COunting the zeros by block is not exact. This formula works if there is no zero in the number (indeed, for 123, it gives 22 zeros, and it's the number of zeros you can find in the numbers between 1 and 123)

Comment: when there any zero in number then what will be the formula? for example 200. @Tryss

Comment: See my new formula. 200 gives you 20+10*((200/10)-1)+200+1-100*(200/100) = 20+10+1 = 31 zero

Comment: How does work the second term of your formula? any proof ? @Tryss

Comment: The idea : remember I said that every 100 numbers, you add 10 zeros, for the numbers xxx**0**0, xxx**0**1, xxx**0**2, ... xxx**0**9. Only the problem is if you're up to one of these number, let's say xxx05, you don't add 10 zeros, but only 6 : the ones corresponding to xxx**0**0, xxx**0**1, ..., xxx**0**5. And for xx0253, there is only 254 zeroes in position xx**0**yyy

Comment: thanks @Tryss , Now its clear.

Answer (score 2):

It is easiest to do it for $1$ to $n$.  Then if you want $m$ to $n$ subtract from $1$ to $m-1$.  If you want the number of zeros up to $13423$, it is the number up to $10000$ plus the number up to $3423$.  Going up to $10000$ note that each place except the $1000$'s contributes the same number of zeros (how many?)  The $1000$'s are none because it would be a leading zero, so going up to $10000$ is $3$ places times $1000$=$3000$.  This should suggest a recursive algorithm.

Comment: it is not clear to me now. please show a calculation for a small number. such as  how many zeroes 1 to 123 ?

Comment: Are you sure about that? Going up to $100$, the tens only contribute 1. Similiarly, there is a zero in 101 that isn't in 1.

Comment: Going up to 100 you get 10 from the ones place.  Going up to 23 you get three more from the ones and 10 from the tens.